# jersey web services with multiple functions

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I m having a jersey class file which I can query correctly without any problem

```
@Path("/hello")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class Hello {

@GET
public String sayPlainTextHello(@QueryParam("t") String t) {
  return "Hello Jersey " + t;
}
}
```

Now how do i can query the two different functions like this -

```
@Path("/hello")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class Hello {

@GET
public String sayPlainTextHello(@QueryParam("t") String t) {
  return "Hello Jersey " + t;
}

@GET
public String sayPlainTextHi(@QueryParam("p") String t,@QueryParam("s") String s) {
  return "Hello Jersey " + t + " " + s;
}    
}
```

On saving this file the web app is not deployed and it says -

```
SEVERE: Producing media type conflict. The resource methods 
public java.lang.String
newa.Hello.sayPlainTextHi(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
and public java.lang.String newa.Hello.sayPlainTextHello(java.lang.String) 
can produce the same media type
```

when i change the the second function produces type to

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

and query the path

```
http://localhost/nvoids/rest/hello?p=hi&s=cool
```

then also it returns

```
Hello Jersey null
```

How can i get both the functions running with different parameters with the common producer to html or different producers like the above example.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`QueryParam` is not a path defining annotation.  Typically, individual resource methods will differ by either method type (e.g. `@GET` vs `@POST` vs `@PUT`) or by path (by marking the method with a unique `@PATH`).  I think you may be able to control the method called by specifying the accept header as well, but wouldn't guarantee it.

For your use case, my recommendation is to consolidate rest endpoint methods and use a delegate approach to your logic; in an if/else block.  See here:

```
@Path("/hello")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class HelloResource {
    @QueryParam("t")
    private String t;

    @QueryParam("p")
    private String p;

    @QueryParam("s")
    private String s;

    @GET
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        if (t != null) {
            return "Hello Jersey " + t;
        } else {
            return "Hello Jersey " + t + " " + s;
        }
    }
}
```